# Issue with backward compatibility (setLatestEventInfo)

Tags: android, android-support-library

In Android 6.0 (API 23) the method `setLatestEventInfo(...)` was completely removed form the class `android.app.Notification`. I know that I have to use now `Notification.Builder(context)....`. The new way works with newer Android versions but I still want to support older Android versions.

For backward compatibility I now added the support library v4 to my gradle file:

`compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1+'`

Unfortunately I still cannot compile the old code with the old method using Android 6.0.

`Error: cannot resolve method setLatestEventInfo(Context,CharSequence,CharSequence,PendingIntent)`

How can I still use the old method to ensure backwards compatibility back to Andoroid 2.3 (API 9)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The new way works with newer Android versions but I still want to support older Android versions.

`android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder`, from the support library that you loaded, works back to API Level 4.

> Unfortunately I still cannot compile the old code with the old method using Android 6.0.

Correct. You should be converting from `setLatestEventInfo()` to using `android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder` from the support library that you loaded.

Specifically, call `setContentTitle()`, `setContentText()`, and `setContentIntent()` to replicate what you got from `setLatestEventInfo()`.

Alternatively, drop your `compileSdkVersion` to 22 or lower. I strongly suspect that `setLatestEventInfo()` is still there, for backwards compatibility reasons, but it is no longer part of the SDK.

Comment: Perfect ! The secret is the class `android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder` . As soon as I use NotificationCompat everything works perfect. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

All of [NotificationCompat.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html) is compatible with Android 1.6 and higher devices - you should use that to support all API levels.